# Tell me how to make a grid responsive

Tags: css, css-grid

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
.grid-container {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap:0px;
  grid-gap: 0px 0px;
 grid-auto-rows: 100px;
 grid-template-areas:
"a a a a b b b b"
"a a a a b b b b"
"c c c c d d d d"
"c c c c d d d d";
align-items: start;
  }

 .item1 {
 grid-area: a;
 width :auto;
 background-color: #037EA7;
 padding: 300px 400px 300px 400px;
  }

.item2 {
  grid-area: b;
  background-color: #FFB400;
  padding:250px 150px 368px;
  margin-left: 100px;
    }

   .item3 {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: #FF5739;
  margin-top: 416px;
  padding: 300px 400px 299px;
   }

    .item4 {
  grid-area: d;
  background-color: #037EA7;
  margin-left: 98px;
  margin-top: 415px;
  padding:250px 150px 368px;
    }
```

This is my css code. I want my css grids to be responsive . Can you tell me what I can add so that the columns on the page do not change shape and no unnecessary space is added so when i change page size only the entire webpage gets smaller or bigger and not the shape of each grid item on the page .

Comment: you have to use media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser and load your page. Then start resizing the browser and see what changes in your layout. Then use media queries to adjust your layout accordingly. If something shifts to left at say 980px, add a media query break point and set a CSS rule that ensures that at 980px that element is kept where you want it. It's not difficult but it does take time. Here are some resources that discuss this topic:

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/css-grid-layout-going-responsive--cms-27270

http://www.creativebloq.com/how-to/create-a-responsive-layout-with-css-grid

https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/common-responsive-layouts-with-css-grid-and-some-without-245a862f48df